# Adding a node to a osmnx MultiDiGraph

Tags: networkx, osmnx

I want to plot a walk between two coordinates. Obviously those two are not exactly represented in nodes.

so my two places I want to plot are described by coordinates:

```
G = ox.graph_from_place("New York, USA", network_type = "walk")
origin = (40.76962427551995, -73.98081598273785) # point 1 close to central park
destination = (40.76382213760314, -73.97369287403389) # point 2 close to central park

origin_node = ox.nearest_nodes(G = G, X = origin[1], Y = origin[0])
destination_node = ox.nearest_nodes(G = G, X = destination[1], Y = destination[0])
route = ox.shortest_path(G, origin_node, destination_node)
```

How can I add my `origin` and `destination` so they can be used without `nearest_node`? Which information would I have to manually provide and how?

Answer (score 0):

Nearest nodes from the network are required to connect user-provided points to the network. If you want to add the two points to the network. One possible solution would be modifying the network in the following possible steps:

1. add nodes using the `graph.add_node(node_id, attrs)` function
2. add edges using the `graph.add_edge(edge_id, attrs)` function

In the attached reference to the documentation, node is indexed by osmid, which you need to create one that does not duplicate osmids in the network. Attributes would be: x, y, street_count, geometry as a `shapely.Point` object.

Edges are indexed by (u,v,key), and from your o/d node to their nearest nodes again with a geometry as a `shapely.LineString` object

https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html?highlight=graph%20from%20gdfs#osmnx.utils_graph.graph_from_gdfs